# How to filter a list of tuples and print out the whole tuple based on that selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I dont know if what Ive said makes sense. But here is my list

```
g_members=
   [(5, "Tom", "Fisher", "Solicitor", "Yes", 24.33, 40),
    (6, "Jane", "Andrews", "Solicitor", "Yes", 24.33, 40),
    (734, "Timothy", "Anders", "Receptionist", "No", 10.33, 16),
    (63 "Vicky", "Smith", "Receptionist", "No", 10.53, 26),
    (64, "Pam", "Bloggs", "Finance Director", "Yes", 28.33, 40),
    (15, "David", "Ustace", "Accountant", "Yes", 26.33, 40),
  ]
```

Im wanting to filter through the list of tuples and print a list of all those that contain 'yes'. so for example

```
     (5,"Tom", "Fisher", "Solicitor", "Yes", 24.33, 40)
     (6, "Jane", "Andrews", "Solicitor", "Yes", 24.33, 40)
     (64, "Pam", "Bloggs", "Finance Director", "Yes", 28.33, 40)
     (15, "David", "Ustace", "Accountant", "Yes", 26.33, 40)
```

I dont know how I would go about this. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: @AndrejKesely your answer is great. Why did you not use the "Your Answer" box?

Comment: @AndrejKesely you were here first, you should write it and get the credit for the answer :)

Comment: I've seen this pattern of answering questions in the comments section of the original question, rather than posting an actual answer. So I was curious why people do that.

Comment: @EmrahDiril - I assume that the downvote button on answers has something to do with it for some users. It doesn't look like the case in this answer though.

Comment: @EmrahDiril I can’t speak for everyone, but I do it when the question is trivial or I expect it to get closed.

Comment: Couldn’t you use a boolean instead of the strings “Yes” and “No”?

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution

```
for member in g_members:
  if member[4] == 'Yes':
    print(member)
```

It works by getting the forth index of each tuple and checks if the value is 'Yes'.
If so, it then prints out the whole tuple

This is my result

```
(5, 'Tom', 'Fisher', 'Solicitor', 'Yes', 24.33, 40)
(6, 'Jane', 'Andrews', 'Solicitor', 'Yes', 24.33, 40)
(64, 'Pam', 'Bloggs', 'Finance Director', 'Yes', 28.33, 40)
(15, 'David', 'Ustace', 'Accountant', 'Yes', 26.33, 40)
```

Answer (score 1):

@AndrejKesely has a nice answer in the comments section to the question:

```
print(*[v for v in g_members if v[4] == 'Yes'], sep='\n')
```

It does the same thing as @Jack's answer but uses [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and [array unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) so it's a concise one-liner.